# Formal definition of "node" with respect to eigenvalues and functional analysis.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-operators

I'm concerned with a special problem of spectral analysis for a certain Sturm-Liouville-differential-operator, that is to say $L:=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-q(x)$ and the spectrum $\sigma(L)$.
While reading an article, I came across the following passage in the text where the author wrote about some properties of the eigenvalue $0$:

"... On the other hand, $0$ is always an eigenvalue of $L$, since $L\varphi'=0$, and it is simple and has a finite number of ***nodes***."

Now, there is the main problem. I don't know in which sense the word "node" should be interpreted. I guess the number of linear independent solutions could be meant but I'm quite unsure with that.

I would be very thankful if anyone knows about that special usage or heard about that once before.

---

Edit:

$q(x):=F'(\varphi(x))$ for a $C^2$-Function $F$ and a bounded nonconstant function $\varphi \in C^2(-\infty,\infty)$ which satisfies the relation $F(\varphi)=\varphi''$. (The boundary conditions aren't mentioned, because they aren't needed-from the theory of Sturm-Liouville-Operators it is known that in case of limit circle at both end points no boundary conditions are necessary to obtain a self-adjoint operator on a suitable domain)

Comment: Something is missing in your statement. What does "=" mean in your quote, and what is $\varphi'$ in $L\varphi'=0$. In a Physics context, "nodes" may mean zeros of the eigenfunction. You haven't specified the interval on which you are working, the endpoint conditions, or the nature of $q$. That leaves a lot in doubt.

Comment: Hello T.A.E., I was sure it doesn't play any role, beacause these specifications will change it to a much more complex problem, but I will edit it. So at first, the meaning of $=$ isn't detemined in a specific way. To my mind it's meant pointwise for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ but here I'm not sure again. In case of the meaning "$=0$ with respect to the $L^2$-inner product it doesn't need to be zero (only almost everywhere)". But maybe my additions will make it possible to be more precisely.

Comment: @MeLoco I think T.A.E. was referring to the symbol $=$ that appears in the quote...
Anyway, I tend to believe nodes could mean zeros of an eigenfunction.

Comment: Oh my god! How could I skip something so blatant? Of course, there schould be $0$ instead of $=$. Sorry and thanks for.

Comment: @MeLoco : Okay, so you are working on $\mathbb{R}$. You need the limit point case at $\pm\infty$ in order to not require conditions (limit circle requires conditions.) So I assume that's what you mean. And $q$ has a very special form, which is why you can find an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Except your note to the lpc respectively lcc. Please Correct me if I'm wrong, but up to this point my knowledge was, that only the lpc at $a$ or $b$ requires conditions (with $L$ on $(a,b)$ where $a,b \in [-\infty,\infty]$). So if I've got the situation of lcc I thought there are no conditions needed?

Comment: Oh yes, I see I switched the cases. I need the conditions only in case of limit circle to obtain a self-adjoint operator. I wrote wrong stuff, you're totally right.

Comment: So maybe on more question? I read about that, w.l.o.g. on can assume, that one point is a regular point, so one can reduce to the problem at $[a,\infty)$ ? Do you know something about that? Is that everytime possible or maybe only under certain limitations?

Comment: @MeLoco : If you assume limit circle case at both $\pm \infty$, then I don't think you'll have to split the interval. In that case, then I believe that all the eigenfunctions (even for real $\lambda$) should be in $L^{2}$. But you probably want the limit point case at both endpoints so that the operators are essentially selfadjoint on compactly supported functions; in that case there are no guarantees that any eigenfunction with real eigenvalue is ever in $L^{2}$ at $+\infty$ or at $-\infty$.

Comment: My aim to plit the interval is caused by the fact that furthermore it is assumed that the limit $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}F'(\varphi(x))=:F'(\varphi_0)$ exists, where $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}\varphi(x)=:\varphi_0$ (absolut value because of symmetry one can show) and I've got some theorems that require a self-adjoint operator acting on $[a,b)$, where a is regular. To use it I need some criterions why I can reduce my problem so that it matches with the requirements of the theorem. So that is why I aimed to split the interval.

Comment: By the fact that $q(x):=F′(φ(x))$ reaches a limit at $+\infty$ respectively at $−\infty$ one can show that there will be (at both points) the limit point case. So I've got no possibility to change or chose the cases at these points, but nevertheless I would like to get a self-adjoint operator (on a suitable doimain), because the most common researches studies only work on self-adjoint operator. So I think it is necessary to force it too, to work with it, isn't it?

Comment: @MeLoco : use the 'at' ping if you want someone to get your message. Selfadjoint guarantees eigenfunction expansions (integrals and/or sums.) Assuming limit-point case at $\pm \infty$: If you want to work on $(-\infty,+\infty)$, then you need $f, Lf\in L^{2}$ and that's all. If you split this into $[a,\infty)$, then the only condition you need other than $f, Lf \in L^{2}$ is $A f(a)+Bf'(a)=0$ where $A$, $B$ are real and not both $0$. Both cases give you selfadjoint operators.